# Debug when "failed to create the sampler"

Tags: rstan

Is it impossible to debug the following error, or is there any corresponding 
 function of `browser()`.
I want to extract objects of the *transformed data block*  in a Stan file when the function `sampling()` fails to create a `stanfit` object.

```
failed to create the sampler; sampling not done
Error in new_CppObject_xp(fields$.module, fields$.pointer, ...) : 
  Exception: binomial_rng: Probability parameter is nan, but must be in the interval [0, 1]  (in 'model23b420c17ad_SBC' at line 247)
```

---

***AN ANSWER:*** A Function `Print()` in a Stan File As a Debugger:

Using print(), we can print any object in the transformed data block, regardless of consequence of the function `rstan::sampling()`.

```
m <- rstan::stan_model(model_code = '
                            data{real x;}
                            transformed data{real z; z =  Phi( (-1.14194+ 2.66963)/(-0.257783) );
                                             print("Here, we can use print() as a debugger")
                                             print("")

                                             print("z = ", z)

                            }
                            parameters {real y;}
                            model {y ~ normal(z,1);}
                            generated quantities {real zhat = z;}')
f <- rstan::sampling(m, data=list(x=1), iter = 100,chains=1)
extract(f)[["zhat"]]
```

As an result of the above toy code, the specified objects in a Stan file are printed in the R console as follows:

```
 > f <- rstan::sampling(m, data=list(x=1), iter = 100,chains=1)
Here, we can use print() as a debugger

z = 1.54953e-009

SAMPLING FOR MODEL 'adff65652652045694506de44240c84c' NOW (CHAIN 1).
Chain 1: 
Chain 1: Gradient evaluation took 0 seconds
Chain 1: 1000 transitions using 10 leapfrog steps per transition would take 0 seconds.
Chain 1: Adjust your expectations accordingly!
Chain 1: 
Chain 1: 
Chain 1: WARNING: There aren't enough warmup iterations to fit the
Chain 1:          three stages of adaptation as currently configured.
Chain 1:          Reducing each adaptation stage to 15%/75%/10% of
Chain 1:          the given number of warmup iterations:
Chain 1:            init_buffer = 7
Chain 1:            adapt_window = 38
Chain 1:            term_buffer = 5
Chain 1: 
Chain 1: Iteration:  1 / 100 [  1%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration: 10 / 100 [ 10%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration: 20 / 100 [ 20%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration: 30 / 100 [ 30%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration: 40 / 100 [ 40%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration: 50 / 100 [ 50%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration: 51 / 100 [ 51%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 60 / 100 [ 60%]  (Sampling)
```

Comment: That error message comes from C++, so R's `browser` function is not going to help you. But the error message is straightforward enough. Most likely, you are passing a probability to `binomial_rng` without first defining it.

Comment: Thank you for reply, and I also think so. But, I intended to define the success rate. Even if sampling fails, I want to know what data are passed to the success rate. Debugging of stan is difficult, only one method with which I come up is that I transfer the code from a stan file in the  transformed data block to R  and use debugger  for R codes.

Comment: You can add `print` statements, but for something like this just working backward from where you call `binomial_rng` should lead you to a symbol that is not defined before you try to use it.

Comment: Thank you @BenGoodrich, it is quite new code for me. It helps me and it specifies where my code has problem as shown in the above. Thank you.